# NHibernate inner join gives "Path expected for join"

Tags: nhibernate, hql, inner-join

I have three Tables:

```
- Person
- User
- PersonSecret
```

where PersonSecret reference to Person and User:

```
<class name="PersonSecret" table="PersonSecret" lazy="false"  >
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">      
                <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
...
<many-to-one  name="Person" class="Person" foreign-key="FK_Person_PersonSecret" lazy="proxy" fetch="select">
    <column name="PersonId"/>
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one  name="User" class="User" foreign-key="FK_User_PersonSecret" lazy="proxy" fetch="select">
    <column name="UserId"/>
</many-to-one>
```

This is the mapping from User to PersonSecret:

```
<set name="PersonSecrets" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" >
<key>
    <column name="UserId"/>
</key>
<one-to-many class="PersonSecret"/>
```

And this from Person to PersonSecret:

```
<set name="PersonSecrets" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" >
<key>
    <column name="PersonId"/>
</key>
<one-to-many class="PersonSecret"/>
```

Now, i try to select all Persons, which has a Entry in PersonSecret for a specific User:

```
var query = this.Session.CreateQuery(@"from Person a inner join PersonSecret b 
          where b.UserId = :userId and b.RemindeBirthday = :remind");
```

This gives me now the ExceptionMessage: "Path expected for join"

Can someone help me, what I am doing wrong? - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your HQL query:

- When using HQL you need to **reference the names of the properties on your model classes** instead of the column names they map to. In this case you should reference the `PersonSecret.User.Id` property in your where clause, instead of the `UserId` column.
- You should also specify the `Person.PersonSecrets` property in the join clause, otherwise NHibernate won't know which columns to join on.
- You should specify your additional filter as a **join condition** using the `with` keyword instead of in the where clause.

Here's the correct version:

```
var query = this.Session.CreateQuery(
    @"from Person as a inner join a.PersonSecrets as b with b.User.Id = :userId and b.RemindeBirthday = :remind");
```

**Related resources:**

- [HQL: The Hibernate Query Language - Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Comment: @t.kehl I was a little to quick in answering this one. I updated my answer with a different solution.

Comment: @Enrico - Can you explain me, how to do this: "specify the Person.PersonSecrets property in the join clause"?

Comment: @t.kehl I've provided you the correct version of the query in my answer. The join clause should be `from Person as a inner join a.PersonSecrets as b`.

Comment: @Enrico - ah sorry - it is working - I haven't seen the s of PersonSecrets :-) - Now it is clear how this works. - Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

you have forgotten the "ON" term.

```
inner join PersonSecret b ON b.PersonId = a.PersonId
```

Comment: HQL doesn't support the SQL join syntax.

Comment: then use CreateSQLQuery instead of CreateQuery